# equals() on List of arrays

Tags: java

Not that I'm trying to put arrays into Lists, I just wondered what would happen.

```
String[] array11 = {"Hello", "world"};
String[] array12 = {"foo", "bar"};

String[] array21 = new String[array11.length];
String[] array22 = new String[array12.length];
System.arraycopy(array11, 0, array21, 0, array11.length);
System.arraycopy(array12, 0, array22, 0, array12.length);

List<String[]> list1 = Arrays.asList(array11, array12);
List<String[]> list2 = Arrays.asList(array21, array22);

System.out.println(list1.equals(list2)); // false
```

Intuitively, the two lists are of course equal. Is there any way to get code like the above to print `true`? Other than implementing my own List and overriding equals() to take arrays into account.

Comment: Arrays don't override `equals` method and use one form Object class which basically calls `==` so it is checking references, meaning array is only equal with itself (it doesn't test for content of arrays). Because of that we have utility methods like `Arrays.equas(arr1, arr2)`. To avoid that kind of problems use lists instead of arrays (generally we shouldn't mix them because arrays don't play well with generic types). You can use something like `List<List<String>> list1 = List.of(Arrays.asList(array1), Arrays.asList(array2))`.

Comment: So basically the answer is "don't mix arrays and Lists". That's fair enough. Is there any technical reason why arrays don't override `equals`?

Comment: @FelixKlenk because they didn't initially, and to change it would break backwards compatibility.

Comment: You can't do it with a `List<String[]>`, because the elements have to be compared using `equals`; but you could compare two `List<List<String>>`s, so compare `Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(array11), Arrays.asList(array12))` with a similarly-constructed list of lists.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `assertArrayEquals(Object[] expecteds, Object[] actuals)`. It's part of org.junit.Assert class.

Comment: I want to compare the Lists, not the arrays within. Those are compared implicitly, and apparently, they are checked for identity not equality. That's my "problem".

Comment: @FelixKlenk that would violate the contract of [`List.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), which requires you use `Object.equals` between the pairwise elements.

Answer (score -2):

In java `.equals()` tests if 2 objects are the exact same object, i.e. "exact" place in memory.  Since you did a copy these are 2 unique arrays as far as Java is concerned.  Adding an element to one will not add it to the other.  You now have 2 lists with 2 arrays in each.

So you can't override `.equals()` to make this specific scenario print true.  You would use `List<List<String>>`like [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31645238/4867303) (more info at that link):

```
List<List<String>> list1 = new ArrayList() {{
    add(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Hello", "world")));
    add(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar")));
}};
 List<List<String>> list2 = new ArrayList()  {{
    add(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Hello", "world")));
    add(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar")));
}};
```

Comment: "exact place in memory" eh?